# Ignore punctuation from counting on a textfield

Tags: regex, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have put a length validator in a textfield but I want to ignore punctuation from counting.

What I have is this:

```
  <v-text-field v-model="note" maxlength="255" dense>
          </v-text-field>
```

What I have tried is replacing the punctuation with empty string:

```
 watch: {
  note(val) {
   if (val) {
   this.note = val.replace(/[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=-_`~()]/g, "")
  }
 }
}
```

But it doesn't work..

Comment: `=-_` creates  a range, does ``this.note = val.replace(/[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]/g, "")`` work?

Comment: It looks like it doesnt count when I print out the length, but than if I try to write 255 chars, it doesn't allow me to write one of these punctuations.

Comment: Then this way is wrong. Try adding `v-validate="{ regex: /^(?:[\p{P}\p{S}]*[^\p{P}\p{S}]){0,255}[\p{P}\p{S}]*$/u }" ` element to the `v-text` element. The `[\p{P}\p{S}]` pattern matches any Unicode punctuation/math symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things **:**

- One is to replace the punctuations with an empty string from the input value (This is what you are trying to do in your code).
- Second is that you just want to ignore the count of the punctuations but don't want to replace them. (I think this is what you want ?)

Here is the live demo as per the second statement (For demo purpose I just put default maxlength as 20) **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    note: null,
    noteMaxLength: 20
  },
  watch: {
    note() {
        this.noteMaxLength = 20;
      const val = this.note.replace(/[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()]/g, "");
      this.noteMaxLength = this.noteMaxLength + (this.note.length - val.length);
      console.log('count', this.noteMaxLength);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="note" :maxlength="noteMaxLength"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below regex in replace code.

```
/[^ \w]+/g
```

Comment: It looks like it doesnt count when I print out the length, but than if I try to write 255 chars, it doesn't allow me to write one of these punctuations.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude alphanumeric characters and spaces characters to get this

```
/[^\w\s]+/g
```

Which works like

- **^**   #Exclude following.
- **\w**  #Word characters.
- **\s**  #Space characters.